# Displaying only the final digit sum in Java

Tags: java

I am currently trying to find out the sum of digits in a number.  However, I am experiencing problems when I display the sum as it still shows all the previous sums, not just the final sum of digits only that I want.

```
int rem = 0, sum = 0, input = 0;
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
input = k.nextInt();

while (input > 0){
    rem = input % 10;
    sum = sum + rem;
    input = input / 10; 
    System.out.println(sum); 
}
```

This is part of my program above. So for example, when I input the number 25, the program outputs the number 5 first then 7. I understand why it inputs the number 5 as it is the remainder when divided by 10 and since I initialised sum = 0 at the start, the first sum will come out as 5 since sum = 0 + 5. However, I only want the final digit sum to be displayed.

How should I approach this problem? 
Any tips and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output is within the while loop, so it will be repeated with every addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while loop` is the thing that compute the sum, so you need to print the result ***after*** the computing :

```
while (input > 0){
    rem = input % 10;
    sum = sum + rem;       //same as : sum += rem
    input = input / 10;    //same as : input /= 10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

---

*Next to that, whith some tricks, and remove* `rem` *variable, this is equivalent :*

```
while (input > 0) {            
    sum += input % 10;  //sum +=rem;   -->   sum += (input%10);
    input /= 10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: `sum += input % 10;' for me is overhacking, doesn't add value to code

Comment: @JacekCz I didn't said that it adds value to code, juste remove one variable and just tell me it exists, but it's not the main subject of the post

Comment: @JacekCz Overhacking, really? That's a first.

Comment: @Gendarme In my opinion, yes. rem (== remainder) is very good variable name (add value to code - programmers intention is clear). My vision best code != the shortest possible, mayby someone has opposite.

Comment: Gendarme, azro - discussion is between good code and good code, based on personal taste. My taste is above

Comment: @JacekCz Heck, I'd have converted the `while` to a `for` loop too, to make a single-statement loop, with no need for braces: `for (; input > 0; input /= 10) sum += input % 10;`. It consolidates the loop logic of division by ten until zero, simply summing the remainder in the loop. If a reader of this code needs to see a variable named `remainder` (or abbreviated `rem`) to understand that `%` is a remainder operation, then reader needs to learn Java better. Coding to uneducated programmers is not "good code". *</opinion>*

Answer (score 0):

Just print the result of the summation after the while loop. You find the every summation result of the number is because you print the result in your while loop.
You should do as follows:

```
while (input > 0){
    rem = input % 10;
    sum = sum + rem;
    input = input / 10;  
}
 System.out.println(sum);
```

if your input is 25, then it will show the summation as 7.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, the issue is that you print out the value of the sum variable inside your while loop.
Either you change your code to:

```
while (input > 0) {            
    sum += input % 10;
    input /= 10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

or you can use streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //1. Step: Read the number
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    Integer input = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();

    //2. Step: calculate the sum with streams
    int sum = String.valueOf(input).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum();

    //3. Step: Print out the result
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
```

Essentially what happens in the second step is this:
We convert the integer into a string, we get the characters of the string and we call for each character using the *map* call the *getNumericValue* method to convert the character back to an integer, then we call the *sum* method to calculate the sum of these integers.